# Guard process doesn't get killed when stopping Rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, guard

I'm starting guard using the binstub in a Procfile

```
guard: bin/guard start
```

When I run the server guard works perfectly but when I terminate it (ctrl-c) there is a problem.

By using `ps aux | grep ruby` I can see that the ruby process(es) are still running, my fan spins up and I need to kill the process manually (using `kill -9 PID`)

```
username     25929 100.0  0.4  2533980  31340 s000  R     3:35AM   0:29.36 ruby /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/_guard-core start
username     25904   0.0  0.1  2474800   5112 s000  S     3:35AM   0:00.23 ruby bin/guard start
```

After killing the process I can find this error message in the logs

```
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |  /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:49:in `exit'                                                
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |  : no implicit conversion from nil to integer (TypeError)
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:49:in `exit_with'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:105:in `block in auto_restart'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:103:in `loop'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:103:in `auto_restart'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from /usr/local/opt/rbenv/versions/2.3.1/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/guard-2.14.1/bin/guard:114:in `<top (required)>'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from bin/guard:17:in `load'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 |   from bin/guard:17:in `<main>'
11:51:06 AM guard.1 Exited with exit code 1
```

Would very much appreciate any help resolving this issue, it is really annoying having to kill the process every time I need to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of **guard: bin/guard start** use guard: guard in your Procfile.

Comment: Try with guard: bundle exec guard in Procfile.

Comment: Which development server are you using to run all commands declared in Procfile?

Comment: Which rails version you are using?